# FluxCI traefik and the stripprefix middleware not being loaded

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm currently using FluxCI to deploy my services to an on prem k8s install. I have ran into some other issues with my personal services so I have boiled one issues down to the prefix that is being passed to my services. Thankfully I can see the issue with the whoami service also.

I tried to copy the "stripprefix" examples when I put this together. Its obviously not working. I'm not getting any visible error when I deploy with `git push && flux reconcile kustomization flux-system --with-source`.

here is my whoami.yaml. I think the issue is with the middleware section, I feel it should some how be integrated into the service section.

Any help would be nice.

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: whoami
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: traefik/whoami
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: web
  selector:
    app: whoami
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /whoami
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: whoami
            port:
              name: web
---
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: whoami-stripprefix
  namespace: default
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /whoami
```

BTW I am testing this by going to the k8s url http://k8scluster/whoami/ and i get this in the response (I removed everything else from the response here).

```
Hostname: whoami-6d97bf7dcb-ldm42
GET /whoami/ HTTP/1.1
```

When I go to traefik's dashboard, I do not see this in the middleware section either.

Answer (score -1):

Since we are not seeing any error message from this concern I suggest to check on the installation of [Flux](https://fluxcd.io/flux/installation/) and [striprefix](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefix/)